# Flame sensor keeps getting dirty?

Tags: hvac, repair, furnace

My father replaced his furnace about a year and half ago.  His flame sensor every 2 weeks to month stops igniting and he will have to take it out to clean it. He's brought in furnace guys numerous times and they have no clue what's wrong with it.  They just clean sensor and give him the bill.

I did read on one post in here that washing machines/dryers in same room may cause the problem as well.  Not sure if this is the issue as house is about 20 years old and he never had this issue before with the old furnace.  With washer/dryer being in the same area.  Any ideas or suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a warranty issue. Maybe the flame isn't adjusted well and is producing soot.

Comment: You might update your post with model information.

Comment: The "flame sensor" is different than the igniter. The job of the igniter to light the gas, the job of the flame sensor is to make sure the igniter successfully did it's job. What is the fuel source? Natural Gas? Propane? Propane tends to burn somewhat dirty, more so than natural gas. When the furnace was installed was it properly commissioned? Did anybody do a combustion exhaust gas analysis to make sure it's operating as efficiently as possible?   If it's running too rich, it could easily foul the sensor.

Comment: What make/model is the current furnace, and is it drawing combustion air from within the laundry room, or from the outside?

Comment: If the "flame sensor" is a thermopile and your pilot is not too rich it can still get premature carbon buildup if placed in the wrong part of the pilot flame.